# Get node position in D3 sankey diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm using the D3 plug-in to make a Sankey diagram, and would like to add labels above each column of nodes.  Something like this:[image]

Is there a function in the sankey object that can return the location of the nodes?

```
var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(15)
    .nodePadding(10)
    .size([width, height]);
```

I'm following the pattern here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/

Comment: If you look at the source code of the example, you'll see that `energy.nodes` provides the data for the coloured rectangles, with the positions determined by the `x` and `y` attributes of the elements. You can use this same information to place the labels.

Comment: Thanks -- I was hoping there was a sharp way to get the position of all "columns" that wasn't looping through the data, but that's certainly a plausible option.

Comment: You could filter this data to get only distinct `x` values, but there's no way to get just the different "levels" with the current implementation.